# COUNT() returning incorrect number of rows

Tags: mysql, count

I am using the MySQL `COUNT()` method to find out how many rows in two tables have the `uid` of u.id.

To do so, I am using the method below:

```
SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.email, u.username, COUNT( q.uid ) AS  `q_count`, COUNT( a.uid ) AS `a_count` 
FROM  `users` AS u
INNER JOIN `questions` AS q ON u.id = q.uid
INNER JOIN `answers` AS a ON u.id = a.uid
WHERE u.username =  'admin'
```

However, when I run the above query, the second count returns the same number of rows as the number of rows for the first count. I know this as the first count is returning two and the second is also doing the same, when there are two rows in the `questions` table and one row in the `answers` table.

Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

---

A sample of what I am receiving: http://d.pr/i/vcnJ

Sample data from `answers`: http://d.pr/i/TMkU

Sample data from `questions`: http://d.pr/i/tuwU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason is that you're doing a JOIN, which will JOIN the results together into one. Do use the same query but with `SELECT *` instead and you will see why this happens.

Try this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.email, u.username, COUNT( DISTINCT q.id ) AS  `q_count`, COUNT( DISTINCT a.id ) AS `a_count` 
FROM  `users` AS u
INNER JOIN `questions` AS q ON u.id = q.uid
INNER JOIN `answers` AS a ON u.id = a.uid
WHERE u.username =  'admin'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't count two tables in one query. `COUNT()` counts rows, not specific values.

What you can do however is

```
SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.email, u.username, 
SUM( CASE WHEN q.uid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS  `q_count`, 
SUM( CASE WHEN a.uid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS `a_count` 
FROM  `users` AS u
LEFT JOIN `questions` AS q ON u.id = q.uid
LEFT JOIN `answers` AS a ON u.id = a.uid
WHERE u.username =  'admin'
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please recommend a better way to do it, or should I just run two individual queries? One retrieving the data from `users` and one of the `count()`s, and the other retrieving the second count?

Comment: Thanks for the provided code, but it returns the same `count()` results as the query I provided in the question.

Comment: @max_ Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Sorry, gotta go now. Will help you later.